# Webpack4 how to load images and custom javascript directly from HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-4

I want to load images directly from HTML with Webpack 4 and add custom Javascript files to my HTML file but both files inspected at console show `Not found 404`.

How to properly load images and Javascipt files with Webpack 4?

My Webpack 4 config file:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../build"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../build"),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    overlay: true
  },
  devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader" // transpiling our JavaScript files using Babel and webpack
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          "postcss-loader", // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
          "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader", // This will resolves import/require() on a file into a url and emits the file into the output directory.
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets",
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: "html-loader",
          options: {
            attrs: ["img:src", ":data-src"],
            minimize: true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // CleanWebpackPlugin will do some clean up/remove folder before build
    // In this case, this plugin will remove 'dist' and 'build' folder before re-build again
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all your webpack bundles in the body using script tags
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "index.html"
    }),
  ]
```

My webpack.prod.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const TerserJSPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack- 
plugin");
const BrotliPlugin = require("brotli-webpack-plugin");
const PurgecssPlugin = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin');
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
entry: {
main: "./src/index.js"
},
output: {
path: path.join(__dirname, "../build"),
filename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].bundle.js",
chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js"
},
mode: "production",
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader" // transpiling our JavaScript files using 
Babel and webpack
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
      "postcss-loader", // Loader for webpack to process CSS with 
PostCSS
      "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by 
default
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
         loader: "file-loader", // This will resolves import/require() 
 on a file into a url and emits the file into the output directory.
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]",
          outputPath: "assets/"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: {
      loader: "html-loader",
      options: {
        attrs: ["img:src", ":data-src"],
        minimize: true
      }
    }
  }
]
},
optimization: {
minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin(), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin()],
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    commons: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      name: "vendors",
      chunks: "all"
    }
  },
  chunks: "all"
},
runtimeChunk: {
  name: "runtime"
}
},
plugins: [
// CleanWebpackPlugin will do some clean up/remove folder before build
// In this case, this plugin will remove 'dist' and 'build' folder 
before re-build again
new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
// PurgecssPlugin will remove unused CSS
new PurgecssPlugin({
  paths: glob.sync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/**/*'), { nodir: 
true })
}),
// This plugin will extract all css to one file
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].bundle.css",
  chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.css",
}),
// The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all 
 your webpack bundles in the body using script tags
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "index.html"
}),
```

My project nesting:

```
--Build
--src
----html
----js
----styles
----assets
------images
```

I want that files would load simply:

```
<img src="assets/images/myimage.jpg">
<srcipt src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Ironically this is my second project with Webpack 4 and this time I can't fix this issue, the first time there was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `img` work in Webpack:

```
<img src=require("./assets/images/myimage.jpg")>
```

if you use "require" with file-loader, you need to add default.

```
 <img src=require("./assets/images/myimage.jpg").default>
```

For script tag, src should be your output `bundle.js` file; because Webpack writes all the code into the `bundle.js` with the help of Babel. So when browser request html, browser will have only one Javascript file which is the bundle to download. That is the whole point of bundle, smaller `bundle.js` is better for performance.

```
// According to your Webpack config, it is main.bundle.js
<srcipt src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

but in order to browser to use this `main.bundle.js`, it has to be publicly available. So you need express to define the public folder, when browser looks for `main.bundle.js`, you app will be looking into the public folder and if that file exists, it will ship it to the browser.

```
const express = require("express");
const server = express();

const staticMiddleware = express.static("build");
server.use(staticMiddleware);
```

Comment: Thanks for you'r time and answer. But images are still not loading, I get the following error:
Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './require("assets/images/portret.jpg")  ' in '/home/viktoras/www/sites/painter-new/src'

Comment: check the path of image. I just modified because it should always starts with "/".

Comment: It should be `<img src={require("./assets/images/myimage.jpg")}>`. Don't forget the curly brackets or it won't work. Also you should point out that the relative file path should be correct for `require` to locate the file.

Comment: it was not mentioned that it is react project.

Comment: Thanks, but images are still not loading and yes, this is not a react project.
I get the following error:
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './require("./assets/images/portret.jpg  ")' in '/home/viktoras/www/sites/painter-new/src':

Comment: what is your script to bundle?

Comment: Updated the post so it would be clear. Added webpack production js file.

Comment: With script, i meant package.json script. “Dev” or “prod”. Because it should be executed webpack. Webpack takes care of require.

Comment: @ViktorasssIT you need to append "default" to the require statement. i updated the answer.